# Não consigo ver os dados do banco de dados na api com django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Estou tentando montar um tabuleiro de xadrez com Django Rest Framework, aí estou querendo apenas que seja as posições sejam carregadas, mas sempre me é retornado apenas "none". Isso ocorre por causa que os últimos registros do banco de dados são realmente "none", mas o meu problema é que está carregando apenas o último valor na api, e não os dados respectivamente. Muito obrigado, desde já!

**Models.py**:

```py
class Board(models.Model):
    chess_board = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']]
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM piecesapp_board')
    con.commit()
    id =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    position_y = ''
    position_x = ''
    piece = 'sda'
    for i in c:   
        position_y = str(i[1])
        position_x = str(i[2])
        piece = str(i[3])
```

**Meu banco de dados(SQLite3)**:

[image]

**Resultado**:

[image]

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Comment: Algum motivo para vocês estar fazendo o SQL manualmente ao invés de usar o ORM do Django?

Comment: As imagens não estão carregando corretamente